# How to get req.hostname when running node.js behind apache with mod_proxy

Tags: node.js, express, mod-proxy

My node.js application uses `req.hostname` in order to redirect some pages from HTTP to HTTPS like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
});
```

This works very well when running the application on localhost. But when the application runs on a server behind mod_proxy then `req.hostname` does not contain the domain name. Instead it contains just `localhost`. How do I get the domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your apache settings you have to add this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

this will tell the apache to preserve a hostname when doing proxy pass to your node application